# How to avoid to re-render children when updating style via props or state in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

At the root of my App I have two **React** components, Menu and Main. The Menu is hidden by translating it to the left outside of the viewport. When it is visible, I also want the Main content to translate to the right. In order to do that I simply pass a *menuOpened* property (boolean) to both components. It will apply a conditional style that setup the CSS transform property translateX(). The problem is, when I update the prop, all the children will re-render. Is there a better practice for changing style of a component depdending of a state / props?

Comment: What's wrong with all children re-rendering ? This should be quite fast, if you aren't modifying anything except the style prop of the top-level container.

Comment: Maybe I am over-estimating the problem. I thought it was weird to re-render everything since I only changed a CSS property.

Comment: You're not re-rendering everything. See my comment below :)

Comment: Read about the way react renders : it computes components that have changed when their props or state have changed (this won't be the case for most components in your subtree, if not all), then builds a virtual DOM, then compares the virtual DOM with the actual DOM, and *only at this point* begins modifying the actual DOM (which is the most expensive part of the cycle). That's what makes it cool : it's never throwing away all the page and re-rendering it anew everytime a single prop value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a comment mentioned - a "rerender" is not expensive. Since almost nothing in your DOM tree has changed, the diff is tiny, and so the actual changes are small.

But if you really want to control when a component re-renders, you can use the React life-cycle method `shouldComponentUpdate(...)`.

Comment: Maybe I am over-estimating the problem. I thought it was weird to re-render everything since I only changed a CSS property.

Comment: Nah it's fine. You're not "re-rendering" everything. React is computing the differences, and only "re-rendering" the differences.

Comment: Alright, however what if I have a compenent which renders a looong array with Array.map(). Even if it's the exact same list, would it still take time to compare all the children? (espacially on an old mobile device for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional class (for example `app_with-menu`) to your App container which indicates if the menu is opened or not. And then style in CSS like this:

```
.app .content {
   // style for content when menu is closed
}
.app.app_with-menu .content {
   // style for content when menu is opened
}
```

Comment: I believe adding the className to the App container will trigger a re-render of the component as well. I'm not 10000% sure, but I don't see why that wouldn't.

Comment: You updated a component's props. This causes React to compute a diff of the DOM tree, and run through life cycle methods for affected components.